weird results from Bai-Ng PCs selection criteria implementation of "dfms" on R
I am trying to select the number of Principal Components of this data following the optimality criteria of Bai and Ng (2002), on R.
The function ICr from the package dfms should conveniently implement Bai and Ng procedure, but the output looks rather weird to me. Specifically, the first principal component explains most of the variance, but the information criteria seem to suggest to take as many factors as number of original variables.
What is going on? How to solve it?
MWE:
library(dfms)

# load the data and remove index column
data <- read.csv("your/path/to/the/csv")

# remove index column
data <- data[,-1]

# execute package's function
ict <- ICr(data, max.r = ncol(data))

# output in pictures below
screeplot(ict)
plot(ict)



